# Does java api for hadoop writing require SSH?

Tags: java, ssh, hadoop

Hi guys :  Im trying to setup writes to a **remote**, single node hadoop instance (remote in that its running on my box in a VM)....

However Im getting the following error (keeps trying to reconnect but cannot).

> 11/10/03 23:03:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:
>   /132.11.665.103:8020. Already tried 7 time(s).

Do I have to setup keyless ssh for my java code to open an input stream to the remote hadoop file server ?

Comment: Is the IP `132.11.665.103:8020` correct as you have mentioned in the core-site.xml file?

Comment: no, i changed the #s for security.  Why does the core-site.xml file matter ?  hadoop is NOT failing internally.... its the client that can't connect.  Inside my VM, I can do normal hadoop operations on data like copying / importing files.

Comment: I mean, whatever IP you get here, is it the same as what you have mentioned in core-site.xml? Just to confirm if the correct core-site.xml file is being picked up

Comment: Why does the core-site.xml require an ip address ?

Comment: The client uses core-site.xml to figure out where to look for HDFS

Comment: I thought the client simply opened a connection to Hadoop via a URI ? That is what the documentation sais ....  Its just a stream... correct?  
 InputStream is = new URL("hdfs://"+IP+"/path").openStream();

Comment: I've never used it that way though.. I am not sure if that works. In any case, Unable to connect means either Hadoop Namenode is not running on that machine, or there is some network problem (check ping, check port). Check the Namenode logs on the remote machine for any problem/exception.

Answer (score 1):

It thinks that the `NameNode` does not exist. Your `core-site.xml` configuration is either incorrect by not pointing to the right `NameNode`, or your `NameNode` has not been started. I found [this resource](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ServerNotAvailable), which describes your problem, I believe.

Most of Hadoop's internal communication is done over plain HTTP, so I can't think of a reason that SSH might be involved.

Comment: No : this is not happening at the namenode.  HDFS works fine inside my VM.  The problem is that , a client OUTSIDE the vm (at another IP address) cant write to hdfs.  internally, hdfs is working fine, I can do simple writes and mvs of text files

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things you can also check.

- See if you are able to ping from the host to the guest.
- Check the firewall setting on the guest.
- Check if the name node port number (8020) is correct.
- Do a netstat on the guest and see if 8020 is open.

The SocketTimeoutException is thrown when you are trying to connect to the namenode.

Comment: I ran this command and the result was that a connection was establishe on 8020 ...... not sure what that means